# Write an array to a file in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write an array to a file with C# and am having issues.
I've started learning c# the last few days and now can't figure out why this happens.

```
    namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Sort()
        {

        }

        public static void Random()
        {
            int[] test2 = new int[5];
            int Min = 1;
            int Max = 100;

            Random randNum = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < test2.Length; i++)
            {
                test2[i] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
                Console.WriteLine(test2[i]);
            }


        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int ii = 0; ii < test2.Length; ii++)
        {
            Array.Sort(test2);
            Console.WriteLine(test2[ii]);
        }


            String writeToText = string.Format("{0}", test2);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\hughesa3\\Desktop\\log.txt", writeToText); // Writes string to text file

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random();
        }
        }
    }
```

It generates a random 5 numbers and puts it into the array, When I try to write this to a file it prints System.Int32[]

I understand that because im trying to print a formated string but how would i go about printing each int ? I've tried using a loop but it will only save the last int as i put it inside the loop?

Can anyone give me some advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `WriteAllLines` and pass string array as input.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("filename", test2.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

or, if you want to write in `,` separated form use this.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filename", string.Join(",", test2.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me, I am trying to write the numbers unsorted first and then below that write them sorted, When I run it now the sorted one will overwrite the unsorted one?

Comment: if you want to sort Just use `OrderBy` Linq extension like `test2>OrderBy(t=>t).Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray()`.

Comment: Array.Sort(test2); works perfectly for this its just when i try to save the sorted array to a file it overwrites the unsorted values

Comment: Use `File.AppendAllLines` instead of `WriteAllLines`.

Comment: Also `AppendAllText` instead of `WriteAllText`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `String writeToText = string.Format("{0}", test2);` calls `ToString` method of the `test2` array and it returns `System.Int32[]`

Change it to

```
String writeToText = string.Join("", test2.Select(x=>x.ToString())
```

or

```
String writeToText = string.Format("{0}", test2.Select(x=>x.ToString().Aggregate((c,n)=>string.Format("{0}{1}", c,n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Add this method and use in System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\hughesa3\\Desktop\\log.txt", ArrayToString(test2));
    public static String ArrayToString(int[] arr)
    {
        return arr.Aggregate("", (current, num) => current + (num + " "));
    }
```